# Python: How to make a circle grow and shrink

Tags: python

I need a circle to grow and shrink infinitely depending on its radius. So if the radius hits 25 then it should shrink and if the radius hits 5 it should grow again.

This is what I have tried so far and all it does is make the circle grow but not shrink:

```
if r < 25:
    r += 1
if r >= 25 and r != 5:
    r -= 1
```

Comment: Code should not be posted as images. Please enter as text and use three backtics to delimit it.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Not seeing any circle here... What framework is drawing this circle?

Comment: Why do you suppose the `if r >= 25 and r != 5` block will be active when the circle is shrinking?

Comment: How can `r >= 25 and r != 5`? I think you wanted to test for the squared radius, therefore something like `r = r + 1 if r ** 2 < 25 else r - 1`

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker Suppose `r` is 100, `r >= 25 and r != 5`...

Comment: btw: `if r >= 25`, then it definitely is `!= 5`

Comment: You should add another variable indicating growth direction.  This is not unlike a bouncing ball issue where you change direction when you reach a limit.  Might I suggest a boolean value, such as `expanding = True`.  then when you hit your max, change to `expanding = False`  use that flag to change your diameter, e.g. `radius = radius+1 if expanding else radius-1`  (but I'd actually use if-then-else block)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I think the point is that we don't know what ZGod wants, and we are guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of whether you are in an increasing phase or in a decreasing phase. So use an extra variable:

```
add = 1  # can be 1 or -1
r = 5
```

Then in the part where you loop:

```
r += add
if r == 25:
    add = -1  # next time we will decrease (until 5)
elif r == 5:  
    add = 1  # next time we will increase (until 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand how your code works. Suppose we start with `r = 23`.

1. Is `r = 23 < 25`? Yes. Set `r = 23 + 1 = 24`
2. Is `r = 24 < 25`? Yes. Set `r = 24 + 1 = 25`
3. Is `r = 25 < 25`? No. Is `r >= 25 and r != 5`? Yes. Set `r = 25 - 1 = 24`
4. Is `r = 24 < 25`? Yes. Set `r = 24 + 1 = 25`
5. Is `r = 25 < 25`? No. Is `r >= 25 and r != 5`? Yes. Set `r = 25 - 1 = 24`
6. Is `r = 24 < 25`? Yes. Set `r = 24 + 1 = 25`
7. Is `r = 25 < 25`? No. Is `r >= 25 and r != 5`? Yes. Set `r = 25 - 1 = 24`
8. Is `r = 24 < 25`? Yes. Set `r = 24 + 1 = 25` ... And so on

No wonder it "gets stuck" at (or close to) `r = 25`).

Instead, keep track of whether the size is increasing or decreasing. Outside the loop, define the variable `increasing`.

```
r = 5
increasing = True
```

Then, inside the loop, change `r` based on whether `increasing` is True.

```
if increasing:
    r += 1
else:
    r -= 1

if r == 25:
    increasing = False
if r == 5:
    increasing = True
```

Remember that we need to flip modes *only when* we reach the limits. So when we reach `r = 25`, we switch `increasing = False`, and when `r = 5` we do the opposite.